# python3 - print decrease progress the same line in win10

Tags: python

I would like print a decrease number the same line in win10.

```
import time
print("start:")

for i in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]:
    print("%d\r"%i,end='',flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
print("done")
```

Current code output:

```
start:
done
```

The number line is missing...

Comment: It's missing because the word "done" overwrites it.  When you write "0\r", that leaves the cursor at the beginning of the line.  Add `time.sleep(1)` in your loop and you'll see it is working.

Comment: Right, sleep saved me but since number is decrease, so after 10, then other number will only update the first char, so the later 0 always there. how can I clear the 0?

Comment: @lucky1928 Do you not want the 0 to be printed?

Comment: I want later print print without any previous remainings.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code as is with the sleep timer and had the numbers appear with the trailing zero.  To make it work as I believe you want, I changed the print statement

```
print("%d\r"%i,end='',flush=True)
```

to

```
print("%d \r"%i,end='',flush=True)
```

That is, I added a trailing space after the format literal.  Give that a try.

Comment: wow, it's smart to add a space there!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for your purpose:

```
print("start:")
for i in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]:
    print(i,end='\r')

print(end='\x1b[2K')
print("\ndone")
```

This code prints all the numbers on one line separated by spaces.

Output:

```
start:
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
done
```

Comment: Thanks, updated the SO with a delay, what I want is only show latest number instead of all number in one line, how to flush old numbers and show new number only? finally it only show 0 at that line

Comment: @lucky1928 Do you want to make a countdown timer?

Comment: right, just like a count down timer

Comment: It's win10, not linux, so \x1b[2K should not work.

Comment: @lucky1928 Does the full code not work or only that particular print statement?

Comment: Looks like not work, need something just like clear to the end just like linux does